# Create live copy of password protected excel workbook

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I have a workbook that is password protected and I’d like to create a read only copy that other users can view on a different location on the network drive.

I know it’s a strange request as the other people could open the original as read only, but we don’t want them to know the location of the original or have anything to do with it, should they figure out my colleagues password.

The other issue we had was that people were opening as read only and it was still telling my colleague that it was locked by another user and he needs it for most of the day so that issue is annoying

Thanks in advance

Comment: Should the copy be password protected, too? Password protected at opening? If yes, they must know the password anyhow... And, if they will be able to open it, they can save it locally, or wherever he want, unprotected and not being read only. So, I think that the issue can be managed through the shared location permissions. Anyhow, this will not eliminate the SaveAs possibility, too... How do you intend to manage the issue regarding "locked by another user"? Creating so many copies in so many locations for all users trying to open it?

Comment: Hey FaneDuru! The other one shouldn’t be password protected and if they change it and save it or save a copy, we don’t particularly care because the original will still be intact and that’s their problem!

Comment: The, when would you like such a copy to be created? And based on what? For how many locations? How the network locations, where the workbook to be copied, will be supplied to the code?

Comment: One copy for the rest of the staff to see. As I said, if they mess it up or make copies etc that’s their problem. 

If I know the basics I can edit any code to match the drives etc. So literally one copy made initially that updates when the main one does

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is add the following event procedure to the ThisWorkbook module:

```
Const RemotePath As String = "D:\YourRemoteLocation\"

Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)
    
    On Error GoTo CleanUp
    
    If Success And InStr(ThisWorkbook.Name, "Copy of ") = 0 Then
        
        Dim CopyFullName As String
        CopyFullName = RemotePath & "Copy of " & ThisWorkbook.Name
        
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        
        Dim fso As FileSystemObject 'Requires the Microsoft Scripting Runtime Library
        Set fso = New FileSystemObject
        fso.CopyFile Source:=ThisWorkbook.FullName, Destination:=CopyFullName
        
        Dim ReadOnlyWorkbook As Workbook
        Set ReadOnlyWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=CopyFullName)
        
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            ReadOnlyWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=CopyFullName, Password:=""
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        ReadOnlyWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
    End If

CleanUp:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Set fso = Nothing

End Sub
```

This code will run every time the workbook is saved and export the current file to the remote location. Then it will open the copy and save it as a workbook without password.

Note that I've added `InStr(ThisWorkbook.Name, "Copy of ") = 0` as a condition to the If-statement. `Instr` returns the position where a substring (arg2) appears in the main string (arg1) or zero if the substring is absent from the main string. In this context, we want it to be zero since we don't want to run the code in the workbook copy.

In this method, the owner of the original file will have to supply their password every time they save. You could automate this by passing the password as an argument to the Open method like this:

```
Set ReadOnlyWorkbook = Workbooks.Open( _
                               Filename:=CopyFullName, _
                               Password:="MyPassword")
```

However, the password would then be accessible by people looking into the VBA code.

Alternatively you could get the password from a local file that wouldn't be accessible from the Network, but then the file path would be visible.

And if the remote folder is not already set to be Read-only mode, you can make sure that people opening the remote version of the file do so in Read-Only mode by adding the following event procedure after the previous one.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    If InStr(ThisWorkbook.Name, "Copy of ") = 0 Then
    
        ThisWorkbook.ChangeFileAccess Mode:=xlReadOnly
    
    End If

End Sub
```

Obviously this will only work if they enable macros.

Comment: Hey!  Thanks for the response and great explanation. I don’t mind putting the password in the code as, in the nicest way possible, the people using it dont even know what VBA is, where to find it and DEFINITELY how to read it. So how would I implement that? Thanks again

Comment: @MarcosisKnows – Sure, no worries. I've just edited the answer to help with that.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the delay. One thing i totally forgot about is that the copy will also have the vba code in, so if they save before quiting will that mess things up? Is there a way to save the copy, but delete all vba from it?

Comment: If you want to remove all macros from the copy, you could save it as a .xlsx file.